# Is net-positive fusion power generation impossible on Earth?

Tags: fusion

I recently ran across a rather interesting claim:

- the Coulomb Barrier equation states that the kinetic energy required to cause nuclei to fuse is greater than the thermal energy released by fusion
- stars get all that energy "for free" by having massive, crushing levels of stellar gravity
- we don't have that level of gravity available Earthside, therefore it's not even theoretically possible to build a viable fusion power plant

The obvious response is, "so then how is it possible that Joe Random Internet Guy can notice this while at the same time it eludes all the professional researchers working on this problem?" but I don't have enough of a physics background to back this up.

Is there a fatal flaw in that line of reasoning, or is net-positive fusion really impossible outside of stellar gravity conditions?

Comment: First part of the claim is wrong for elements lighter than iron.

Comment: On SE we'd normally expect/hope people would provide a link to the source of a claim (or make a detailed statement of where the claim can be found).  I can't say, off-hand, that I'm aware of an actual proof that non-stellar fusion can make an "energy profit", so it's an interesting question.

Comment: Of course it isn't.

Comment: Thermonuclear weapons exist.

Comment: That's not an "interesting claim". That's someone saying "I know there's people that have made the calculations correctly, but I'm not even going to bother looking those up, let alone do them myself, and instead conclude what I wanted to conclude in the first place".

Comment: see https://www.iter.org/sci/BeyondITER

Answer (score 2):

While it is true that the kinetic energy required to pass the Coulomb barrier *might* be larger than the energy released in a fusion reaction, there is something missing here: we don't actually need to climb up all the way to the Coulomb wall. There is already a finite probability at much lower energies that **tunneling** through the Coulomb barrier takes place.

An example: let's take 2 protons, like in the sun. The height of the Coulomb barrier of 2 protons that you need to overcome in order to be close enough so that the strong force takes over (which is roughly at a distance of the particles' radii) can be estimated to $1.2\,\mathrm{MeV}$. From measurements, however, we know that the sun's core temperature is only on the order of $1\,\mathrm{keV}$, which is 3 orders of magnitude too low. The solution is tunneling (and that we don't need "all" particles to fuse but only some in the tail of a Maxwellian distribution to have a sustained fusion reaction).

It is true that the sun's concept does not work on earth and we are looking into different concepts where the most promising seems to be magnetic confinement fusion. Also, we are not aiming on mimicking that highly inefficient process on the sun in the lab: for a single proton to fuse with another one, it takes on the order of $10^{10}$ years in the sun. We are looking into the D-T reaction, which is more efficient but also requires a higher average temperature, something on the order of $20\,\mathrm{keV}$.

Breakthrough has not yet been achieved in the lab, ITER (currently under construction) is the first experiment that is supposed to demonstrate that. The record so far was achieved in JET, where 60 % of the input power was released in a fusion reaction.

(And a source/reference for that claim would be nice.)

**Edit:** Well, an experimental "prove" was in principle given by the hydrogen bombs, where you have a fission bomb to provide the energy needed to start the fusion process resulting in a much higher energy release, which translates into a much larger explosion. Note, however, that this is very different from the magnetic confinement approach, which is inherently safe by design but that is a different story.

Comment: "While it is true that the kinetic energy required to pass the Coulomb barrier is larger than the energy released in a fusion reaction" - this does not seem true for deuterium and tritium.

Comment: @akhmeteli true, well spotted (will change now)